# Using Tor browser to use YouTube and account security

Tags: passwords, tor

YouTube is not available in my country, but I want to make an account on YouTube and use it. I'm not interested in protecting my identity. It is fine if anyone can monitor it. The thing I'm interested in is that I don't want my YouTube account compromised. I want to make sure that my YouTube's username and password (and other secret questions etc.) should remain secure.

I also don't have any problem if someone can do (middle-man-attack) to retrieve my video contents, since my videos will be public.

Is it possible achieve what I've listed above?

Comment: please use a VPN/Proxy instead of Tor!

Answer (score 3):

As you can see youtube URL is: https://www.youtube.com/. It starts with http"S", so your connection is encrypted for sure. So no worry about your Account Security.

In addition, when you want to sign up for Youtube, what you need actually is to create a Google Account via this URL: https://accounts.google.com.
Again, this is http"S", so it is end-to-end encryption from your PC to Google server. Those guys in middle without really strong decryption tool cannot get your password.

However, as DJCrashdummy just mentioned under your post. I also recommend you use VPN instead of Tor for watching video, cos Video definitely costs a lot of bandwidth of Tor, while this bandwidth is really important and necessary for other people who needs it. Also, Streaming Video over Tor does not provide you a smooth view, so I suggest you try this VPN: https://www.softether.org/, it's developed by Tsukuba University, Japan, and even China Great Firewall cannot block it. Last but not least, it's totally free.